# Website scraping with python3 & beautifulsoup 4

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm starting to make progress on a website scraper, but I've run into two snags. Here is the code first:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get("http://www.nytimes.com")
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text)

headlines=soup.find_all(class_="story-heading")
for headline in headlines:
 print (headline)
```

**Questions**

- Why do you a have to use `find_all(class_= blahblahblah)`
  Instead of just `find_all(blahblahblah)`? I realize that the `story-heading` is a class of its own, but can't I just search all the HTML using `find_all` and get the same results? The notes for BeautifulSoup show find_all.a returning all the anchor tags in an HTML document, why won't `find_all("story-heading")` do the same?

  Is it because if I try and do that, it will just find all the instances of "story-heading" within the HTML and return those? I am trying to get python to return everything in that tag. That's my best guess.
- Why do I get all this extra junk code? Should my requests to find all just show me everything within the story-header tag? I'm getting a lot more text than what I am just trying to specify.

Comment: Format your code as code and not just regular text in the post so we can read it

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful Soup allows you use CSS Selectors. Look in the [doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for "CSS selector"

You can find all elements with class "story-heading" like so:

```
soup.find_all(".story-heading")
```

If instead it's you're looking for id's just do

```
soup.find_all("#id-name")
```